# Добавление В к словам, начинающимся на О

Tags: лингвистика

Для чего к некоторым словам, начинающимся на О, добавляют впереди букву В: острый-вострый, восемь-осемь? И, кстати, в одних случаях почему-то прижился вариант с В, а в других - без.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для чего - это вопрос не совсем корректный. Целенаправленности в таких вещах нет и вряд ли может быть.

Тут надо спрашивать об исторических процессах, предопределивших данную тенденцию.
В русском языке в определенный исторический момент действовал закон, по которому слог всегда начинался с согласного. Зияние гласных и гласный в абсолютном начале слова исключались.

При этом А обычно переходил в Я (=ЙА), У - в ВУ, О - в ВО и Е(=ЙЭ). Последнее объясняется тем, что О и Е и до того часто переходили друг в друга.

В отношении слов, начинающихся с Э (в основном междометия) и с И единого мнения нет. Возможно, что указанный закон на них совсем не действовал. Либо они тоже звучали как ЙЭ и ЙИ, но это не нашло отражения на письме.

Такое наращение согласных - типичный пример т.н. протезы  или наращения, часто даже сам термин сводят именно к такому значению (хотя, полагаю, не совсем верно, тут был спор недавно).

> И, кстати, в одних случаях почему-то прижился вариант с В, а в других - без

Закон не был абсолютным, в разных случаях его действие проявлялось с разной интенсивностью. Кроме того, закон действовал в строго ограниченный период (два-три века после первого разделения славянских), на слова, образованные или заимствованные  после, он не действовал. Хотя в отдельных случаях стремление добавить такую протезу сохранилось до сих пор. Каких-то конкретных условий, влияющих на закрепление и нормативность протетического варианта, насколько знаю, не выявлено.